# AggregateException not being caught?

Tags: c#, exception, stream

I'm querying a remote server and sometimes get an `AggregateException`. This is fairly rare and I know how to get around when this happens, but for some reason, it's not entering the `catch` block whenever the exception is thrown.

This is the code part for the catch block:

```
try
{
    using (Stream stream = await MyQuery(parameters))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return content;
    }
}
catch (AggregateException exception)
{
    exception.Handle((innerException) =>
    {
        if (innerException is IOException && innerException.InnerException is SocketException)
        {
            DoSomething();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

And this is the exception message I'm getting:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I'm assuming those --> arrows indicate that it's an inner exception right?
So if it's IOException -> SocketException, why is `DoSomething()` never called?

Comment: Have you looked at this in a debugger?

Comment: No.. as I said, it doesn't happen very often.

Comment: Well I'd *at least* add some logging then...

Comment: I think someone with more knowledge than I will correct me, but the `async/await` pattern has an underlying state machine, and it "unwraps" the `AggregateException` for you and throws the original typed Exception. So you'd want to just catch your `IOException` rather than the `AggregateException`.

Comment: [MSDN AggerateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're not actually seeing an `AggregateException` at this point. There's nothing in the code you have that is doing parallel operations.

If that's correct, you should be able to do something like this:

```
try
{
  using (Stream stream = await MyQuery(parameters))
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
  {
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return content;
  }
}
catch (IOException exception)
{
  if (exception.InnerException is SocketException)
    DoSomething();
  else
    throw;
}
```